# Executing "python setup.py install" inside an iPython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I recently downloaded some software that requires one to change to the directory with python files, and run `python setup.py install --user` in the Terminal.

One then checks whether the code is running correctly by trying `from [x] import [y]`

This works on my Terminal. However, when I then try `from [x] import [y]` in the notebook, it never works. So, this makes me think I must install the `setup.py` file within the iPython notebook.

How does one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, installing a python module in the terminal is sufficient. There is not such thing as installing within the IPython notebook.

Simply restart your IPython notebook after the install. If it still does not work, you are probably not using the same python interpreter between the two: check python version (`which python`), make sure you are not using a virtual environment, and that `$PYTHON_PATH` is not somehow different, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong version of the iPython notebook.

Perhaps you've been using `ipython3 notebook` instead of `ipython notebook` or vice-versa. If Python2.7 has the package you want, it won't work if you try to import it into the `ipython3 notebook`.

If there's a version mismatch then you can usually just get the relevant package using a `sudo pip3 install package_name` or `sudo pip install package_name` depending on the version you want.

Of course pip can be obtained by `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` for Python 3 and `sudo apt-get install python-pip` for Python2.7.